# Trouble with getting form data using Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I am super new to front end development.  I have a simple webapp where you can submit a form, and I want to be able to get the form data in a REST endpoint. I am using Spring boot which contains Spring MVC.

The HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header modal-header-info">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Entity</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="/createEntity">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text"
                class="form-control" id="name">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEntity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createEntity(@RequestBody String payload) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    System.out.println(payload);
}
```

I get this error back:

```
Failed to read HTTP message:
           org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
           Required request body is missing: public void    main.java.info.spring.data.neo4j.controllers.CreateEntityController.createEntity(java.lang.String)
```

How do I get the "name" value from the form? The "hello world" attribute prints out if I take out the @RequestBody part.

Edit: my configuration per request:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "main.java.info.spring.data.neo4j.services",
        "main.java.info.spring.data.neo4j.controllers" })
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "main.java.info.spring.data.neo4j.repositories")
public class MyNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public static final String URL = System.getenv("NEO4J_URL") != null ? System.getenv("NEO4J_URL")
            : "http://localhost:7474";

    @Override
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new RemoteServer(URL, "neo4j", "LOL my pass");

    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("main.java.info.spring.data.neo4j.domain");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your configuration?

Comment: Look at **Problem 1** in @manish's answer. It really could be the problem, because inputs without name can be considered as incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Problem 1**: HTML form controls are missing the `name` attribute

HTML forms are submitted in name-value pairs. Form controls that do not have a `name` attribute cannot be submitted because their names are not known. The `id` attribute is only for referencing controls on the client-side.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
```

is missing the `name` attribute.  It should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
```

This will submit the control as a form parameter in the HTTP request body, something like:

```
name: [the value you specify for the control]
```

> **Problem 2**: `@RequestBody` as a controller method argument will give you the entire HTTP request body

```
public void createEntity(@RequestBody String payload)
```

means that you want the entire HTTP request body to be passed as a `String` to the controller method `createEntity`.  If your HTML form is indeed what you have posted, you will get the following value for `payload` (after you have addressed problem 1):

```
name: [the value you specify for the control]
```

If this is what you want, keep the `@RequestBody` annotation, but I suspect that you are only interested in the value of the `name` request parameter.  If that is the case, you need to change your method declaration to (after you have addressed problem 1):

```
public void createEntity(@RequestParam String name)
```

This will map the HTTP request parameter `name` to the controller method argument `name`.

> **Problem 3**: Having `void` as the return type for a controller method will force Spring MVC to look for a view with the same name as the method name

Since you have the controller method declared as:

```
public void createEntity(@RequestBody String payload)
```

Spring MVC will look for a view named `createEntity` after this method exits.  If you have a view with that name, well and good.  Otherwise, once you have fixed problems 1 and 2, you will get a `404 - Resource not found` error.

Comment: **Problem 2**: in this case `StringHttpMessageConverter` will be used. And this converter does NOT need name conventions, since it returns all text of request body.

Comment: **Problem 3**: `void` return type is OK for REST Controller's methods.

Comment: This works, thanks for answering the question politely.